# Teamcity build trigger after a certain number of check ins

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

Is there a way to trigger a teamcity build only after a certain number of check ins. I tried checking build triggering in teamcity but can't find anything where I can specify the number of check in after whcih I want to trigger a build.

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to postpone build for several commits?

Comment: Because i have artifacts associated with each build and I want to save the space on teamcity server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built in solution to this, but there are some things you could do.

- Build your own build trigger plugin as described in the [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Custom+Build+Trigger)
- You may be able to simulate what you want by setting a long quiet period in the VCS trigger.
- Use a scheduled trigger to run every hour or more and set it to only run the build if changes are detected

Only the first option will trigger on a specific number of checkins, but the other two could reduce the number of builds you do a day.

You can also look into the [artifact clean up rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Clean-Up) to reduce the number of artifacts kept. Another option is to use [pinned builds](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Pinned+Build) to pin one build a day (for example) that will not get cleaned up by the artifact clean up process.